# Activerecord has_and_belongs_to_many with nested groups

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, relational-database, self-referencing-table

I need to store groups of users in other groups, somewhat like Windows Active Directory.

I have the following what works

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users do |table|
    table.column :name, :string
  end
  create_table :groups do |table|
    table.column :name, :string
  end
  create_join_table :users, :groups do |t|
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

peter  = User.create(id: 1, Name: 'Peter')
thomas = User.create(id: 2, Name: 'Thomas')
inf = Group.create(id: 1, Name: 'Informatics')

peter.groups << inf
inf.users << thomas
p User.find_by(Name: 'Peter').groups
p Group.find_by(Name: 'Informatics').users
```

But I would like to do the following also

```
sm = Group.create(id: 2, Name: 'System')
inf.groups << sm
```

What would be the simplest way to do so ?

Comment: You need to look into Self-Referential Association. Some examples are [here](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/07/30/bi-directional-and-self-referential-associations-in-rails) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

Comment: Is there any reason you are using has_and_belongs_to over has_many => through? The latter may be a little more flexible.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon groups can have many users and groups, users can have many groups, is that possible with has_many_through ? why more flexible ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: you retain flexibility without (really any) corresponding cost. what if you want to add extra fields to your join table / join model? what if you want to have callbacks and validation logic in your join model in the future? you retain that additional flexibility, and for free.

Comment: @peter here is a link to the docs discussing this issue: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: @AbM Thnx for the links, the thing is there is code that is executed in controllers and after creating and deleting, I would like to avoid that so that the tables are usable with plain SQL also and SRA is apparently more about bi-directional functionality and not nesting

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I see, I was going for simple, for the moment don't need any of the extra's, just want the nesting, but I'm testing that approach now also, Thnx for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using a Self-Referential relation in your `Group` model. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.

Basically, the `parent_id` for main groups will be `NULL` and the sub groups will have their `parent_id` set to the column id of their parent group.

**Group Model:**

```
has_many :users

has_many :sub_groups, class_name: "Group", foreign_key: :parent_id
has_many :sub_group_users, through: :sub_groups, source: :users 
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
# This is a scope to load the top level groups and eager-load their users, sub-groups, and the sub-groups' users too.
scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :users, sub_groups: :users}
```

**Groups Controller:**

```
def show
  @group            = Group.find(params[:id])
  @category         = @group.parent
  @users            = @group.users
  @sub_group        = @group.sub_groups.first
  unless @sub_group.nil?
    @relatives      = @group.sub_group_users
  end
end

private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_group)
  end


  def main_group
    @group = Group.parent_id.nil?
  end
```

In your `groups` table, add this column: `t.integer "parent_id"`

In your `users` table, add this column: `t.integer "group_id"`

You will need to add `:group_id` into your `user_params` as well (in your users controller).

**User Model:** `belongs_to :group`

In your groups show view:

```
<% if @category %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>

  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% @relatives&.each do |user| %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, that's a start, I'v put my attemt to use this in a separate answer, feel free to modify that or yours. I will accept only solution from you or others, not my own attempts

Comment: @peter Oh, I'm sorry, I was thinking you where running Ruby with the Rails framework. I should also add that I think my solution will only work to display users if they are a part of a subgroup. They can belong to a main group but I think I was running into issues when trying to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I put my attemtp with Jake's solution here in a separate answer to keep it apart from the original and make comments and edits on this solution alone possible.
It is NOT my intention to accept this as an answer !
Also I put the entire script here so that people can test right away.
The solution uses only 2 tables instead of the original 3 which is good but it's not complete yet, see my remarks at the end of the code.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'logger'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => "sqlite3",
:database  => ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users do |table|
    table.column :name, :string
    table.column :group_id, :integer
  end
  create_table :groups do |table|
    table.column :name, :string
    table.column :user_id, :integer
    table.column :parent_id, :integer
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :sub_groups, class_name: "Group", foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :sub_group_users, through: :sub_groups, source: :users 
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
  # This is a scope to load the top level groups and eager-load their users, sub-groups, and the sub-groups' users too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :users, sub_groups: :users}
end

peter  = User.create(id: 1, name: 'Peter')
thomas = User.create(id: 2, name: 'Thomas')
erika  = User.create(id: 3, name: 'Erika')
inf    = Group.create(id: 1, name: 'Informatics')
devs   = Group.create(id: 2, name: 'Devs')
log    = Group.create(id: 3, name: 'Logistics')

# peter.groups << inf # doesn't work
devs.users << thomas
devs.users << peter
inf.users << erika

# expect inf.groups << devs to work
inf.sub_groups << devs

# doesn't work
p peter.groups #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

# only gives users added straight to the group
p inf.users #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 3, name: "Erika", group_id: 1>]>

# this should be added to inf.users
p inf.sub_group_users 
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1, name: "Peter", group_id: 2>, #<User id: 2, name: "Thomas", group_id: 2>]>

# works
p Group.top_level
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Group id: 1, name: "Informatics", user_id: nil, parent_id: nil>]>
```